# What is the proper way to reference another model from within a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have two models: Reptile and Species. A Reptile has a Species, stored as an ID in the database:
[image]

How should I set up the details controller action/view for Reptile so that it displays the Title property of the Species instead of the ID that the Reptile uses?

My initial thought was just to grab the data in the controller and pass it in the ViewBag, but this seems inappropriate, and overly complex when it's time to setup the list action.

What's the proper way to do this?

It seems like I need to make a view model, but what confuses me is how to properly design it so that there aren't too many database calls.

Here is my initial attempt at a ViewModel:

```
public class ReptileDetailsModel
{
    [Required]
    public String Species { get; set; }

    //etc...

    public ReptileDetailsModel(Reptile reptile)
    {
        this.Species = reptile.Species.Title;

        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you're going down the right path

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve the same thing in more generic way is to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Few advantages I can think of:

- Automatically map exact properties (you only need specify anything that is exception to the rule)
- Centralized in one class / method, whatever
- Ability to ignore, map to another classes properties, even custom logic
- Non intrusive, it is up to you how / when you want to use it.

In your particular instance I would create a mapper something like

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Reptile, ReptileDetailsModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Species, 
        options => options.MapFrom(source => source.Species.Title));
```

This mapper info need to be registered somewhere. In MVC projects I have been involved, I would register a mapper into global.asax.

Then in your controller, you would want to invoke the mapper to map your reptile instance to your model

```
ReptileDetailsModel model = Mapper.Map<ReptileDetailsModel>(reptile);
```

There are many ways to use the AutoMapper within MVC, but this is probably a start.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize it at the time, but I was using:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var db = new ModelsContainer())
    {
        return View(db.Reptiles.ToList());
    }
}
```

This was causing the database (and thus model property) to expire before the view was rendered, causing this error (adding for search engines):

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

Comment: You should edit your question with this information, it doesn't look like it's answering the question you asked... does it?

Comment: I suppose it could be explained better. Once you remove the using statement, it works fine and the second model's information is available to the view. This is a function of the entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Species class as a model for your strongly typed Reptile View. Then display the Title property of it. Your action method should look like this:

```
public ActionResult Reptile(Reptile rep)
{
    return View(db.Species.Where(x=>x.ID == rep.SpeciesID).Single());
}
```

this way you would only need to call database once in order to generate the view.